# Set Leaflet map to height: 100% of container

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, height, leaflet

Please how can we set the map div to be height: 100% of its container?

I have tried this within a bootstrap template content section, but all I get is height of 0px. Even Google-Dev tools shows #map height as 0px.

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
html, body, #map {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Is #map a direct descendant of body?

Comment: Make sure that all of the ancestors of #map have a height of 100% and it should work.

Comment: @jme11 im using AdminLTE as my bootstrap template... it would be quite difficult to make these changes all the way up without affecting the overall working of the template

Comment: It seems that we both have the same issue. Can't seem to figure out how to stretch the leaflet map to cover the entire bootstrap container [template_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjSju.png). I tried the answers below and few other answers on the Internet, but none has work so far. Here are my html [html_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81nNv.png) and my CSS [css_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUUgJ.png). Are there other workarounds to fix my issue? especially without using javascript since I'm a newbie and don't know about Javascript. I'm Rendering the map using folium inside a Django app btw.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Set

```
#map{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

and give its container `position: relative`.

Comment: You're going to need to give more context for the html structure of AdminLTE.  It's not at all clear what's not working here.  In short: one of the parent elements of your #map element will need a fixed height/width.  You can only set `#map { height: 100%; }` if one of it's parents has fixed height.

Answer (score 10):

The above answer didn't work for me, but this did:

```
   body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    html, body, #map {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

..from [A full screen leaflet.js map](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/7654694)

Answer (score 2):

Leaflet needs an absolute height, and `height: 100%` only refers to the **height of the parent element** - if this isn't set, it will default to 0.

If your map is the only element in the body, use `height: 100vh` to match the height of the viewport ([Example](https://jsfiddle.net/jamedeus/tuvhcs0p/)).

If your map is inside a container, set `height: 100vh` on the container (or other desired height) and `height: 100%` on the map element ([Example](https://jsfiddle.net/jamedeus/q2wde7fh/)).

Comment: Actually a good and explanatory answer, thanks