# Creating Map With Leaflet and OpenStreetMap

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary, leaflet, openstreetmap

I want use leaflet map and try as following code, but it don't work true and the map is still not displayed.
How can run it?

```js
var map = L.map('map');

L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 18,
    id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
    tileSize: 512,
    zoomOffset: -1,
    accessToken: 'your.mapbox.access.token'
}).addTo(map);

var marker = L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map);
var circle = L.circle([51.508, -0.11], {
    color: 'red',
    fillColor: '#f03',
    fillOpacity: 0.5,
    radius: 500
}).addTo(map);
```

```css
#map {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.6.0/leaflet.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.6.0/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="map"></div>
```

EX: https://jsfiddle.net/n6rLykfx/

Comment: Ah, the classic "map container has zero height" problem. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29773850/set-leaflet-map-to-height-100-of-container

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set Leaflet map to height: 100% of container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29773850/set-leaflet-map-to-height-100-of-container)

Comment: @IvanSanchez But the map is still not displayed: https://jsfiddle.net/n6rLykfx/

Comment: ...because you're not setting an initial center/zoom for the map. This is all covered in https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/